# G+zz simultaneously : Move to bottom and then move text to center?

Tags: key-bindings, cursor-motions

How do i remap `G` to do what `G` and `zz` do **simultaneously** ? In other words, I would like to move to the bottom of the page and then have the text moved to the middle of the screen.

I tried something like :

```
nnoremap G :norm Gzz<CR>
```

But Im getting the error : `command too recursive`

Comment: You need `:norm!` to make it non-recursive. See `:help :norm` for more details. You can also just simply use `nnoremap G Gzz`, no?

Comment: Yeah, just gonna say the same thing. `nnoremap` (and `nmap`) are for specifying _Normal mode_ key maps. That means they accept Normal mode commands without having to use `:norm[!]`.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Hopefully filbranden/B Layer will post an answer; if not, I will CW one.

Comment: I don't think I can claim any first rights to answer this one but if I could I relinquish them...will be away for a while. :)

Comment: @BLayer enjoy the time :)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thank you. It was just for a day, though. :)

Answer (score 3):

It is as simple as

```
nnoremap G Gzz
```

No need to go into ex-mode. You want to bind G to do what Gzz would do originally.